# How to check if a BufferedImage is complete in java?

Tags: java, file-upload, bufferedimage

I'm trying to load an image from a server, with the following code:

```
BufferedImage img;    
do{
    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
    }catch (IOException e){}
}while(img == null);
```

The idea is to keep checking source until the image is found, because it will be uploaded while the code is still executing. The problem is that when the image is still being loaded to the server the code stops, showing a fraction of the image, because it is no longer null but it's still not complete, so how can I check if the image is complete?

Comment: It looks like what should be fixed is the server: it should respond with a 404 Not Found until the image has been fully uploaded. And only then, it should start serving it.

Comment: Redoing the same operation while it keeps throwing an `IOException` that you keep ignoring is utterly futile. Why would it work the second and subsequent times if it didn't work the first time? How about you (a) print the stack trace of the exception and (b) post it here? Edit it into your post.

Answer (score 0):

From within an Applet I handle image loading like this:

```
MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(this);
Image image = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "image-filename.png");
mediaTracker.addImage(image, 0);
try {
    mediaTracker.waitForAll();
} catch (InterruptedException interuptedException) {
    interuptedException.printStackTrace();
}
```